# How to send CC Email in Freeform v2 Expressionengine

Tags: ee7

I've read official documentation but did not find any tag where I can send CC and BCC email notification after submit, if anyone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are tow types of notifications. Admin and visitor. For a cc or bcc for vistor you just add an extra e-mail-field I guess. For the admin notification just click the mail button next to the settings within the form and select a notification template. An area show up where your can put mailadressen "Email address(es) to receive an email notification. Enter each on a new line."
Mails wil be send like a BCC.[[image]]

[[image]

Comment: This shoots email to both the emails and I dont want to send it separately.